# Loading Highcharts within an angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-scope, highcharts-ng

I am trying to replicate the chart found here: http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/Hjdnw/ within my angular app.

However, unlike in the example above, i am using version 1.2.28 instead of v1.0..

I have replicated my set up here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ugIbk80yBXuvjsUFhiiP?p=preview

However i am getting 2 errors in the console:

1. TypeError: HighchartsAdapter is undefined
2. Error: H is not a function

Does the order of script loading matter? I am following:

```
<script data-semver="1.2.28" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
<script src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts-ng.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add jQuery to make highcharts work properly

See working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9YToY5auOWvh5R3LC2N1?p=preview)

I've added

```
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, however this link suggests you can use highcharts without jQuery: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Comment: @OamPsy, without jquery you have to use Highcharts' Standalone Adapter (else, it will not work):

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>